# Move files to folder by date in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have few files named as per **year+month+date** format.

Example:

20220101
20220102
20220103
20220104
..
20220130
20220131

As the file generated daily, I need to move 1st 2(20220101,20220102) and last 2(20220130,20220131) files in a specific folder every month. Can someone help me out how can I write the script?

Answer (score 1):

This helped me a long back -

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=/Users/limeworks/Downloads/target
target=$DIR
cd "$DIR"

for file in *; do
    # Top tear folder name
    year=$(stat -f "%Sm" -t "%Y" $file)
    # Secondary folder name
    subfolderName=$(stat -f "%Sm" -t "%d-%m-%Y" $file)

    if [ ! -d "$target/$year" ]; then
        mkdir "$target/$year"
        echo "starting new year: $year"
    fi
    if [ ! -d "$target/$year/$subfolderName" ]; then
        mkdir "$target/$year/$subfolderName"
        echo "starting new day & month folder: $subfolderName"
    fi
    echo "moving file $file"
    mv "$file" "$target/$year/$subfolderName"

done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ string="20220101 20220102 20220103 20220104 .. 20220130 20220131" 
$ awk '{ print |"mv " $1" "$2" "$(NF-1)" "$NF " /your/folder"}' <<<"$string"
```

or

```
$ myArray=(20220101 20220102 20220103 20220104 .. 20220130 20220131)
$ mv ${myArray[0]} ${myArray[1]} ${myArray[-2]} ${myArray[-1]} /your/folder
```

Files to array

```
$ myArray=($(find /path/to/files -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" -print0))
```

or

```
$ readarray myArray < <(find /path/to/files -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]")
```

Comment: thankyou @ufopilot ..as the files are generated daily so how can i specify the string or array?

Comment: @MuhtasinHaque answer updated

Answer (score 0):

well if you want to do this in bash i would suggest having a single script file and one log file to keep track of the current month/previous month.

```
#!/bin/bash
x=$(date +%D | cut -c 4,5 | sed 's|0||g')
y=$(sed -n 1p date.log 2>/dev/null) 
if ! [ -d date.log ]; then
  printf "$x" > date.log
  exit 0
fi
if [[ $y -ge 0 && $y -le 12 && $x != $y ]]; then
  #if the current month equal the previous month then everthing here will be exicuted
  echo "a new month is here"
else
  sed -i "1s/^.*$/$x/" date.log
fi
```

what this script essentially dose is that it creates log file containing the current month "if it doesn't already exist and". After that "if executed again" it matches the new month value to the one contained in the log file if it doesn't match it executes everything where the commented text is which is most likely a bunch of mv commands.

Comment: thank you @tomas ..each file has been generated everyday as per above format. I have to move 4 files(1st 2 days of the month and last 2days of the month) every month to a specific folder.

Comment: wait, i made a mistake it's not supposed to be x=$(date +%d | sed 's|0||g'). it's supposed to be x=$(date +%D | cut -c 4,5 | sed 's|0||g') it's taking the day of the month not the month it's self so i fixed it . I just got confused cause today is the 6'th.

Comment: this is also not automated so you will have to contemplate for that

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

datefiles=( 20[0-9][0-9][01][0-9][0-3][0-9] )
mv -n -v -- "${datefiles[@]:0:2}" "${datefiles[@]: -2}" /path/to/folder
```

- `datefiles=( 20[0-9][0-9][01][0-9][0-3][0-9] )` makes an array of the files in the current directory with date-formatted names, sorted by name.
- `"${datefiles[@]:0:2}"` expands to the first two elements in the `datefiles` array.
- `"${datefiles[@]: -2}"` expands to the last two elements in the `datefiles` array.
- You'll need to change `/path/to/folder`.
- Unless it is absolutely guaranteed that there will always be at least 4 date files, you should add a check on the number of files found (eg. `if (( ${#datefiles[*]} >= 4 )) ...`).

Answer (score 0):

My purpose has been served.

`

```
for i in {1..12}; do
   mv $(date -d "20220101 $i months" +'%Y%m%d') /path/to/folder/
   mv $(date -d "20220102 $i months" +'%Y%m%d') /path/to/folder/
   mv $(date -d "20220101 + $i month - 1 day" +'%Y%m%d') /path/to/folder/
   mv $(date -d "20220101 + $i month - 2 day" +'%Y%m%d') /path/to/folder/
done
```

`
that's the solution.

thanks everyone who has been participated.